# How to handle passwords for i.e. databases or ftp servers in an application

Tags: security, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways around putting a password in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214582/ways-around-putting-a-password-in-code)

If you create an application that for example connects to a database or an ftp server it needs a username and a password.

How do you recommend storing this?

First and easiest option is of course as plain text in the application, but then I guess it would be quite clear and visible if you somehow decompiled the application (or the application was already in clear text in the case of php etc.). But is there any way around this? Could of course encrypt it, but then you would have to decrypt it which (although I may be wrong) usually requires something like a password or a token of some sort. And then you are back at the beginning, cause where do you store *that* password/token?

What are some good practices in this area?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214582/ways-around-putting-a-password-in-code

Comment: Deal. Just close this one then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to this SO question

[Ways around putting a password in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214582/ways-around-putting-a-password-in-code/1214689#1214689)

Since, you did not mention the platform, I am assuming Windows. I am reproducing my answer to that question here.

You have multiple options here.

1.You can hash the password the very first time and store the hash to a file. Now the next time, you want to execute the code with elevated privileges, you need to accept/retype the password and re-compute the hash and match it with the stored hash. Only if it matches will you execute your code in elevation modes. You could hash using SHA. Please look at System.Crytography namespace for examples on hashing.

2.Second option is to encrypt the password using algorithms like AES. However you will need to have a key to do this and you will have to worry about securing this key.

3.Third option is to use DPAPI and encrypt the password but not worry about securing the keys - much easier option than 2.

I would recommend 1 if you do not mind re-entering the password every time the application starts. If that is not a possibility, I would suggest going with 3 and use DPAPI.

Here are some links to get you started.

1.http://www.obviex.com/samples/dpapi.aspx 2. http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx

Comment: The suggestion to hash the password fails to take the rainbow table attack into account. The password must be "salted" before it is hashed. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000949.html

Comment: Also, don't copy-paste your own answers if you can link to them.

Comment: I will mark this as accepted for the effort anyways. Will read more in the related question :)